# How to run a set of callables in parallel by using Flowable and Single

Tags: java, parallel-processing, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-java3

I have 4 blocking operations and would like to run them in parallel by using RxJava Single/Flowable.

The test code that I wrote to check parallelism is:

```
final Single<Boolean> f1 = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    System.out.println("f1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return true;
});
final Single<Boolean> f2 = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("f2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return true;
});
final Single<Boolean> f3 = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    System.out.println("f3 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return true;
});
final Single<Boolean> f4 = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("f4 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return true;
});

Flowable.fromArray(f1, f2, f3, f4)
        .flatMap(Single::toFlowable)
        .parallel(4)
        .runOn(Schedulers.io())
        .sequential()
        .ignoreElements()
        .blockingAwait();
```

However they run all on the same thread, sequentially giving the following output:

```
f1 Test worker
f2 Test worker
f3 Test worker
f4 Test worker
```

despite the time delays in f1 and f3...

Using `Flowable.parallel` works fine with flowables of values but now in this case. So I am missing something.

How can I make my code work or how can I run callables in parallel in a elegant way by using RxJava?

Comment: Put the `flatMap(Single::toFlowable)` between `runOn` and `sequential`